# Is there a limit to the number of subdirectories I can create?

Tags: directory

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Release: 18.04 and I want to know if there's a maximum of directories that I can't go beyond?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for `ext4` systems every file or directory uses an *inode*, of which a limited amount are pre-allocated when the disk is first formatted. You can see what percentage of this is used by running this command:

```
df -hi
```

Look at the `IUse%` column. For most situations this never be exhausted, but it's possible this can lead to problems if you start out on a small disk (and therefor not many inodes) and later resize to a larger disk since inodes are not re-allocated when growing a partition. In those cases you would want to copy the file system from a small disk to a larger disk in a special way.

Comment: Outside of the inode limit, there's also the path length limit, so while you might be able to create a 1000 directories, you might not be able to do `/1/2/3/.../1000`.

Comment: There isn't a "strict" limit on total path length, only each individual file name itself. A program that uses relative paths can address paths of infinite length, see https://serverfault.com/a/9553/46631